# How to best use @tf.function decorator for class methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

To examplify my problem with a minimal example, suppose I would like to create a class in the spirit of

```py
class test_a:
    def __init__(self, X):
        self.X = X
    def predict(self, a):
        return a * self.X
```

Importantly, the `predict()` function should change if I assign a new `X` to an instance of `test_a`.
In this example it works fine:

```py
X = tf.ones((1, 1))
a = test_a(X)
y = tf.ones((1, 1))
a.predict(y) # output [[1.]]

# now I want to change the value of a.X
Xnew = 2 * tf.ones((1, 1))
a.X = Xnew
a.predict(y) # output [[2.]], as desired.
```

Now suppose I want to use the `@tf.function` decorator to speed up `predict()`.

```py
class test_b:
    def __init__(self, X):
        self.X = X
        
    @tf.function
    def predict(self, a):
        return a * self.X
```

Now the following undesired behavior occurs:

```py
X = tf.ones((1, 1))
b = test_b(X)
y = tf.ones((1, 1))
b.predict(y) # output [[1.]]

# now I want to change the value of b.X
Xnew = 2 * tf.ones((1, 1))
b.X = Xnew
b.predict(y) # output is still [[1.]], but I would like it to be [[2.]]
```

The only idea I have so far is having a method `_predict(X, a)`, which I could then decorate and then call `_predict(self.X, a)` inside the (not decorated) method `predict(self, a)`.
Any help how this could be done better would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think `self.X` should be `tf.Variable(trainable=False)`. And you have to use `tf.Variable.assign()` to change it. To avoid python side effects

Comment: Thank you very much, this changes make the code work as desired!
However, I noticed that I get the following warning:

"""
WARNING:tensorflow:7 out of the last 11 calls to <function test_b.predict at 0x7f1494c0ce50> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. 
"""

Does this mean a new graph is created every time I assign a new value to self.X ?
Would that be a problem?

Comment: new graph is built every time you call the model with a new shape

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, that helps me. A problem which arises from this suggestion is that I would like it to be possible that the shape of X changes. Using self.X.assign(...) I get an error when the shapes dont match. How could I change the shape of X using assign?

Comment: I don't think it is possible with tf.function. I am even not sure whether it is possible in eager mode

Answer (score 2):

To avoid python side effects - `self.X` should be `tf.Variable(trainable=False)`. And you have to use `tf.Variable.assign()` to change it.